# Life-support for plants: How can I re-grow my plants from half-dry stems

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, germination, propagation

So, I got a couple of roses, ivy, holly, jasmine, porthos and gardenia plants back in December, but now they all seem to be near-death. I have tried several times to resurrect some of my plants using their stems but no success to date. With half-dry stems, can I still get my plants back? I would appreciate expert help in getting this right this time please.

Comment: Do you have pictures and do you have an idea *why* they are near death? No water or too much, insects, frost bite or sunburn, fungal disease, run over by a lawn mower...

Comment: What's happened to the roots then, that you're trying to generate new plants from half dead stems? Are the roots compromised? Are they in pots, in the ground? Need much more info please...

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert but what I have used for grape vines is this [rooting powder](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bonide-Rooting-Powder-925/202251696).
I took the extra step and shaved the bark from the donor stem about an inch from the bottom before dipping the stem into the powder and then planting. The planted vines started right off and are showing great promise after only a few months.